# Sorting dictionary both descending and ascending in Python

Tags: python

I want to sort the dictionary by values. If the values are the same, then I want to sort it by keys.

For example, if I have the string "bitter butter a butter baggy", output has to be [(butter,2),(a,1),(baggy,1),(bitter,1)).

My below code sorts the dictionary by values in descending order. But I am not able to do the second part, i.e. if the values are same, then I have sort keys in ascending order.

```
def count_words(s,n):
  words = s.split(" ")
  wordcount = {}
  for word in words:
   if word not in wordcount:
    wordcount[word] = 1
   else:
    wordcount[word] += 1
  sorted_x = sorted(wordcount.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
  sorted_asc = sorted(wordcount.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
 return sorted_x
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned what the issue is... that might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, what you need is to write a comparator which sorts the values by count first and if they are equal then it sorts the values by the keys.

```
from collections import defaultdict


def count_words(s):
    def comparator(first, second):
        if first[1] > second[1]:
            return 1
        elif first[1] < second[1]:
            return -1

        if first[0] > second[0]:
            return -1
        elif first[0] == second[0]:
            return 0
        return 1

    words = s.split(" ")
    wordcount = defaultdict(int)

    for word in words:
        wordcount[word] += 1

    return sorted(wordcount.items(), cmp=comparator, reverse=True)


print count_words("bitter butter a c batter butter baggy")
```

> [('butter', 2), ('a', 1), ('baggy', 1), ('batter', 1), ('bitter', 1), ('c', 1)]

Comment: Thanks, If values are same, then the keys has to be in ascending order. So the output has to be (butter,2)(a,1)(baggy,1)(batter,1),(bitter,1)(c,1)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this would help

```
s = { "A":1, "B":1,  "C":1, "D":0, "E":2, "F":0 }
rez = sorted(s.items(), key = lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
```

Result is

```
[('D', 0), ('F', 0), ('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('C', 1), ('E', 2)]
```

If you need a reversed order, just use -x[1] instead of x[1]